# Query works in phpMyAdmin but not PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In phpMyAdmin I have a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM `recent` WHERE datediff(now(), `timestamp`) > 1
```

BUT when I try to do this in my clear_recent.php:

```
<?php $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `recent` WHERE datediff(now(), `timestamp`) > 1"); ?>
    <?php foreach ($result->fetch_assoc() as $row): ?>
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo($title = $row["id"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo($title = $row["pid"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo($title = $row["user_id"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo($title = $row["timestamp"]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I get an error:

*Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /database/chron/clear_recent.php*

Cannot for the life of my figure out what's wrong!!!! Please help!

Comment: get rid of your foreach loop and just have the while loop. [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Do a var_dump of the $result before the loop and post its contents

Comment: Wes Foster I did a var dump of $result and got this: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the query returns any row. try the following code.

```
<?php 
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `recent` WHERE datediff(now(), `timestamp`) > 1");
    $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

    //check if some rows available.
    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            while ($row = $rows) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo($title = $row["id"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo($title = $row["pid"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo($title = $row["user_id"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo($title = $row["timestamp"]); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php 
            }
        } 
    } 
?>
```

additional question: why you use while loop under the foreach loop? is it right?

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly. I didn't realize that if it wasn't returning any rows I'd get an error. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why I used a while loop. I copied the code somewhere from the internet but it does work...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because no rows return from this query.